# Full Body Detection with OpenCV & C++

Tags: c++, opencv, ar.drone

I am using opencv for full body detection on my AR.Drone and wanted to know what would be good settings/limits for the minSize and maxSize parameters? As of now I have them blank, my code seems to detect people fairly well. I also have the minNeighbors parameter set to 7. Each time I run my code I get about 20% false positives. My hope is that setting the size parameters will reduce the amount of false positives. Any input or suggestions on other parameter settings in addition to the size parameters will be helpful

Answer (score 0):

The size parameters, in this case, are scene dependent. You have to check the results on several images/sequences and see the distribution of sizes of both true positives and false positives. After observing the range of values for each category, you can adjust the minSize and maxSize.

Most likely, you will come to a point where you still have some false positives and some false negatives. At this point, you can decide the threshold values by considering which is more costly to have; false positives, or false negatives.

Another approach is to post-process the results returned by the recogniser, and remove false positives based on some other criteria.